# Verify access/group in Passport.js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I would like to use passport.js to verify that when users hit certain endpoints that they not only have the correct password but are a member of a specific group or have a certain access.

For simplicity sake if I have access levels of USER and ADMIN.

I can use passport to authenticate a password:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

Then with a route I can make sure the user passes auth:

```
app.get('/api/users',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    res.json({ ... });
  });
```

But lets say you need to have ADMIN acess to hit /api/users'.  Do I need to write my own Strategies?  IE do I need to have a local-user, and local-admin strategy, and in each verify the proper access levels?

I think I can do this pretty easily, but the problem arises when I need my site to have different auth methods (maybe sometimes use oauth), I would need to write custom *-user, *-admin strategies for each.  Seems like overkill.

Other option is to just verify access/group in each route after the user has been authenticated.  But I would prefer to do this in the middle-ware if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could create a simple middleware that checks the group:

```
var needsGroup = function(group) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user && req.user.group === group)
      next();
    else
      res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
  };
};

app.get('/api/users', 
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  needsGroup('admin'), 
  function(req, res) {
    ...
  });
```

This assumes that the object stored in `req.user` has a property `group`. This object is the one passed along from the strategy implementation and `deserializeUser`.

An alternative could be [connect-roles](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/connect-roles), but I don't know how well that integrates with Passport.

**EDIT:** you could also combine Passport and the group-checking middleware:

```
var needsGroup = function(group) {
  return [
    passport.authenticate('local'),
    function(req, res, next) {
      if (req.user && req.user.group === group)
        next();
      else
        res.send(401, 'Unauthorized');
    }
  ];
};

app.get('/api/users', needsGroup('admin'), function(req, res) {
});
```

Comment: Oh, I see.  Looks like you can use an array of 'middle-ware' functions that are called in order with express.  Did not even realize that, must has missed it.  Time to read the manual again ;)  Thanks, this is perfect!

Comment: Yup, there it is: 'app.VERB(path, [callback...], callback)'.  Sorry I missed that and thanks for being so kind with your answer!

Comment: What I'm looking is an optional authentication:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806339/passport-js-optional-authentication

Comment: I know this is super nit picky, but I think a 403 is probably more appropriate of a response in this scenario. Authentication has passed via passport at that point, so really it's an unauthorized request.

Comment: my problem is my roles are dynamic  from backend api how to handle in that scenario any suggestion ??